# how to resize a div with the browser window using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to re-size a `div`'s height with the browser window using JavaScript or jQuery getting the windows object dimensions and creating a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind to the `resize` event to well... re-size your element:

```
//bind event handler to the `resize` event
$(window).on('resize', function () {

    //cache the window object for use in this function
    var $this = $(this);

    //set the height of my object to the height of the window
    $('#my-object').height($this.height());

//trigger a window resize to initialize the object's height
}).trigger('resize');
```

`$this` refers to the `window` object.

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and replaces the depreciated `.bind()` in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a crossbrowser solution:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/4bF44/)

I divided the result by 'two' to make the effect more visible at window resize:

```
$.getDocHeight = function(){
  var D = document;
  return Math.max(Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight), Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight), Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight));
};

$('#box').height($.getDocHeight()/2 );

$(window).resize(function(){
  $('#box').height($.getDocHeight()/2 );
});
```

You can just use:

```
$('#box').height($.getDocHeight);
```

Hope this helps - Happy coding!